# Bootstrap modal window error

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm just starting to learn ROR and currently make my own first app - ToDo list. I almoust finished it, it worked fine, BUT I wanted to improve the look by changing the CSS. I do not know the reason, but now when I click "New task" modal window opens with an error on the whole page and it is inactive. See [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/xqqknop31/). Experimental way I removed all the changes in the css, but the problem is not solved.

There css settings for modal window:

> .modal form {
>       margin-bottom: 10;
>   }
>
> span.error { 
>   color: red; 
>   margin-left: 5px; 
>   }

And this is html.haml for it:

> .modal-header
>     %h2 
>       = task.new_record? ? 'New Task'  :  "Edit task #{task.title}"
>   = simple_form_for @task, class: 'clearfix', remote: true do |f|
>     .modal-body
>       = f.input :title
>       = f.input :note
>       = f.input :completed, as: :string, input_html: { class: 'datepicker', value: task.completed.present? ? localize(task.completed, format: '%d/%m/%Y') : nil }
>     .modal-footer
>       = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary'

If need to send some other code that I can do it. I would be grateful for any help!

ADDED: There is html.haml of layout where is button of modal:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title ToDo
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    #header/
    %h1 ToDo
    %p time management application
  .text-center
    = link_to 'New task', new_task_path, class: 'btn btn-primary', remote: true
  .text-right
    %strong= current_user.email
  .text-right
    = link_to 'logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
  = yield
```

ADDED2. Yes, the modal is triggered via javascript. There is code:

```
m = $('#modal');
m.html('<%= j(render partial: 'task_form', locals: {task: @task}) %>');
m.modal('show');
$('#modal').integrateDatepicker();
```

And I do not quite understand - html.haml code for modal posted above ... (start from *.modal-header*)

I tried to check all potential pages through bootlint, but no error is found.

Comment: Can you also post the html/haml or the button that triggers the modal?

Comment: Have you [Bootlinted](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) your page?

Comment: @NorthLegion, I see. So the modal is triggered via javascript? If so can you also post the JS code? Also can you inspect element and post the rendered HTML source for the modal too?